# How to run scripts before running/building flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So in node i would run script through the package JSON with NPM.
I'm doing the same now with flutter but what is the proper way doing this?
I taught pub spec Yamal is the same as package JSON for dart but i didn't find how to add scripts.